# Why the image didn't come out in python?

Tags: python

I try to add image in tkinter but it didn't show up but when I added label of text,the text show but the image didn't.Thank you

```
from tkinter import *
class window1:
def __init__(self, parent, word, geometry):
    # image
    bank_img = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject3\\bank-988164_640.png')

    self.parent = parent
    self.word = word
    self.geometry = geometry
    parent.geometry(geometry)
    parent.title(self.word)

    # Label
    label = Label(parent, text="Welcome to the bank", height=3).pack()
    bank_logo = Label(parent,image=bank_img).pack()
root = Tk()
app = window1(root, 'beginner bank system', '300x300')
```

[image]

Comment: can you edit the code, the indentation in the code seems wrong.

Comment: Can you replace `bank_img` with `self.bank_img` and try again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tkinter PhotoImage not displaying gif properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554204/python-tkinter-photoimage-not-displaying-gif-properly)

Comment: Okay, tested above change myself and it indeed solved the problem. So this question is a duplicate of [Python Tkinter PhotoImage not displaying gif properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554204/python-tkinter-photoimage-not-displaying-gif-properly)

Answer (score 0):

Add root.mainloop() at the end.

```
root = Tk()
app = window1(root, 'beginner bank system', '300x300')
root.mainloop()
```